# How to find out sip users of a specific template are online in asterisk?

Tags: asterisk, sip, agi, user-presence

I have 2 kinds of sip extensions. Clients and agents, is it possible to find out how many clients and how many and which agents are available on run-time? In dialplan or AGI.

Comment: does `sip show registry` or `sip show peers` on the CLI shows the desired information for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can do only

```
asterisk -rx "sip show peer"
```

or similar command via AMI

There are no agent tracking code inside asterisk. If you need tracking, name extensions like agent_extensionname or use database to match agent/extension.